# wso2 esb retry configuration

Tags: wso2, esb

I am using wso2 esb4.9 on windows7. The JDK is 7.0.

I want to let esb to retry 5 times when timeout error happens.

ESB log display 5 times retry...
But there is no retry log is printed...

```
<endpoint name="Sample_First" statistics="enable" >
    <address uri="http://localhost/myendpoint" statistics="enable" trace="disable">
        <timeout>
            <duration>60000</duration>
        </timeout>

        <markForSuspension>
            <errorCodes>101504, 101505</errorCodes>
            <retriesBeforeSuspension>5</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            <retryDelay>1</retryDelay>
        </markForSuspension>

        <suspendOnFailure>
            <errorCodes>101500, 101501, 101506, 101507, 101508</errorCodes>
            <initialDuration>1000</initialDuration>
            <progressionFactor>2</progressionFactor>
            <maximumDuration>60000</maximumDuration>
        </suspendOnFailure>

    </address>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `ESB log display 5 times retry... But there is no retry log is printed...`?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you are asking whether ESB tries to connect to the endpoint 4 more times if it gets timed out (fails to connect). This is not the idea of `<retriesBeforeSuspension>` tag. This integer means ESB marks that endpoint as a SUSPENDED endpoint if 4(as per your configuration) more requests get timed out consecutively. These other requests should be done manually and its not done by ESB automatically. Thats the reason you don't see retry log 5 times.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot, this explanation looks make sense and reasonable.